# Unable to render partials with handlebars and assemblefile.js

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, assemble

I'm using the [updated documentation for Assemble.js](https://github.com/assemble/assemble) and am having a hard time getting a clear picture of how to use Partial includes within subfolders using Handlebars.

The only meaningful reference I've found to partial config in `assemblefile.js` is in the deprecated [gulp-assemble doc site](https://github.com/assemble/gulp-assemble).

[Assemble.io](http://assemble.io/docs/Partials.html) isn't helpful since it's not up-to-date with the [latest github repo](https://github.com/assemble/assemble).

Here's my assemblefile.js:

```js
'use strict';

var assemble = require('assemble');
var app = assemble();
var streamRename = require('stream-rename');
var markdown = require('helper-markdown');

app.helper('markdown', require('helper-markdown'));

app.task('load', function(callback) {
  app.partials(['templates/partials/*.hbs']);
  app.pages(['templates/*.hbs']);
  callback();
})

app.task('assemble', ['load'], function() {
  return app.toStream('pages')
    .pipe(app.renderFile())
    .pipe(streamRename({extname:'.html'}))
    .pipe(app.dest("./"));
});

app.task('default', ['assemble']);

module.exports = app;
```

My file structure:

```
root
---/templates
------index.hbs
------/partials
---------myPartial.hbs
```

When I try to invoke the partial from `index.hbs` with:

```
{{> partials/myPartial.hbs}}
```

The assemble task generates this error:

> The partial partials/myPartial.hbs could not be found

How do I include Handlebars partials within subdirectories with a simple Assemble build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `stem` of the partial filename:

```
{{> myPartial }}
```

There's also a built-in helper called `partial` that attempts to find the partial by the key (like `myPartial`) or other properties like `path` (`partials/myPartial.hbs`)

```
{{partial 'myPartial'}}
```

More information about how the templates work together can be found in the [templates readme](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/templates). These docs are also linked to from the [assemble readme](https://github.com/assemble/assemble#templates-api).

Comment: Thanks! Removing the extra path and extension worked (though I thought I had already tried that in troubleshooting).